# Unable to access Azure container through browser

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, azure-storage-account

This is the error showing in browser when I hit the url of container:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

> ResourceNotFound
>
> The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:3fc3c275-301e-000f-3193-f99692000000 Time:2022-11-16T08:13:12.8837824Z

But I am able to access the blob when I hit the URL of blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the Same in my environment in got the same error as below:***

[image]

To resolve this issue, try to give access in container  url with SAS token like below:

[image]

And generate a SAS token and include it in below Url:

```
https://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<containername>?restype=container&comp=list&<sas-token>
```

When I ran the same, I got the result successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: So are you able to access the container through browser ?

Comment: Yes, please check the above image

Comment: Did Everything ass per your instructions still unable to access.

Comment: Unable to attach screenshots but I did everything same as you did.

Comment: <Error>
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:1466acb6-601e-006e-66bd-f91e28000000 Time:2022-11-16T13:16:14.5910757Z</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>sr is mandatory. Cannot be empty</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>

Comment: Tried by removing "?" from SAS token, still got same error.

Comment: Make sure in container you should your container name not container url

Comment: Thank you Imran, I can now successfully access it on browser.

Comment: But I want to access container through browser, but I can only see XML file. I cannot access images and videos.

Comment: Okay, so it means I cannot access contents of container through its URI, so I need to access each blob file with different URL ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Right click to your container folder and then select change access level and you are done!

Comment: I did that but I still it cannot be accessible over browser

Comment: Did you select blob or container in the drop down list? I selected container (anonymous read access for containers and blobs) option.

Comment: I did the same but the the container can't be accessed, I can only  access the blobs.

Comment: Maybe you dont have permission to change the access level. For more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=portal#set-the-public-access-level-for-a-container